# Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. [ apache,xampp,phpmyadmin ]

Tags: apache, xampp

when I try to open apache
this erorr apears:

```
2:45:49 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
2:45:49 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:45:49 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:45:49 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:45:49 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:45:49 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
2:45:49 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I tried to change th port and copy paste from the backup file to data file and didn't work

I think if I reinstall it will work but I have databases and sites in `HTDOCS` what do I do

Comment: Is there something you installed before it stop woking? Any configs you edited?

Comment: I didn't install any thing before the erorr , but I edited the ports after the erorr from 80 to 8080 and from 443 to 4433

Comment: Provide more info. Show httpd.conf, vhost.conf. Check if all paths correct

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the phpMyAdmin application, so I've removed the phpMyAdmin tag for you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to xampp and open your apache config you will see there `httpd.conf` open it, scroll down and find

> Listen 80

Change it to

> Listen 8080

Then scroll down and find

> ServerName localhost:80

And change it to

> ServerName localhost:8080

I think the information was useful. It worked for me...

Comment: yup useful and worked in the one before this but this one didn't work so i reinstalled the software,
thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to fix this problem –**

1. Stop the XAMPP server, MySQL and Apache
2. Create a backup of the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder using a compression software
3. Rename the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder to “/xampp/mysql/data-old”
4. Create a new folder and name it “/xampp/mysql/data”
5. Copy all folders from the “/xampp/mysql/backup” and paste it to the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder, which you have just created
6. Copy all the databases from the “/xampp/mysql/data-old” folder and paste it to the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder
7. Finally copy the “ibdata1” and all of the log files including “ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 ” from “/xampp/mysql/data-old” and paste it to the “/xampp/mysql/data” folder

**Start MySQL from the XAMPP control panel**

**Go to phpMyAdmin to check if all the databases are available and running properly**